# Using mod rewrite to use urls without query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use mod rwerite but I simply cant figure it out...

The way I understand it, the following should be possible:

When a user clicks on a link like this `<a href="/contents/folder/somepage_17">Linktext</a>` then I should be able to make the server believe that I want `/contents/folder/somepage.php?id=17` and then access the query string via `$_GET` in the somepage.php file, right?

If so, how would I put that in mod rewrite syntax? Also, I have lots of pages that have dashes in their names, so I'd have quite a high number of URLs like this `this-is-a-page_19`.

Currently, all my URLs have the query string already in them (like `/abc/de/page.php?id=12`) but I'd like to have URRLs without query string. However, I need some kind of information, which page is being called because I then access a database to get some information about that page (title, keywords, description,...).

Help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contents/folder/somepage_([0-9]+)$ /contents/folder/somepage.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

And you can then access the GET var using $_GET['id']